# Get View class from activity using reflections

Tags: java, android, reflection

Is there any way I can get `View` `field` in `Activity`. I mean something like this:

```
Field test = MyActivity.this.getDeclaredField("android.view.View");
```

I need it to set `field` `setAccesible(true)`, so I can access `private fields` of `View`

EDIT:
I can access listeners like this:

```
listenerInfoField = Class.forName("android.view.View").getDeclaredField("mListenerInfo");
        if (listenerInfoField != null) {
            listenerInfoField.setAccessible(true);
        }
```

but it works only in API 14+, because mListenerInfo field is private in previous API's. I want to get View field to set it accessible, so I can get private fields from it.

Comment: your question is not clear to me. Please explain a bit more

Comment: Briefly explained what I want!